# Can InDesign paragraph styles be exported out as XML or CSS for review?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, css, cc-2014, paragraph-styles

I've been spending more time in InDesign's paragraph styles I've found where a document can be created with set styles and used as a template but Im trying to figure out how I can review that InDesign document's styles when I get them from a colleague.

I've found lately only after manual review of the style that when I receive the `.indd` file back and build a book from a group of `.indd` files that InDesign will produce multiple stylesheets on the export and Im trying to figure out why that is happening.  It would be apparent that its because small adjustments to the individual stylesheets are being made in their `Paragraph Style Options` panel but I would like to find a better way to confirm that or to see if an option exists that Im unsure of.

In CC-2014 is there a way to export ALL styles from the document so it can be stored and possibly imported to prevent this issue?  I do not see it in the options panel but all I see is `Load Paragraph Styles`:

[image]

The [documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/paragraph-character-styles.html#add_paragraph_and_character_styles) is limited on using Paragraph Styles from multiple documents so if my understanding is incorrect please educate me.

I've reviewed `Edit All Export Tags` and they are set to automatic but I don't think that would be an issue.  I am thinking I might have to find or write a script to do this but my questions are:

- Can Paragraph Styles be exported out as XML or CSS for review?
- Can multiple `.indd` file's paragraph styles be consolidated or minified on export to prevent multiple sheet generation?
- When exporting an InDesign book is there a way in the panel to consolidate all files or replace all file's styles without having to go to each one and manually doing it?

I do have a script after export that consolidates and sorts all styles but only after the book is generated.  I could possibly script it to delete multiple duplicates but my goal in the question is to figure out *why* InDesign is doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright here we go:

Check the export Tags Panel

[image]

Then go ahead and Export HTML, then open the idGeneratedStyles.css file in your preferred editor:

[image]

---

For the second part of your question one possible solution would be to make a Master Stylesheet using XML and import it into the different parts of your book. Though if you did the Master Stylesheet correctly I'm really quite sure it should go across the book already, off the top of my head though it's been too long since I did a large .indb project to remember exact. Anyways here's a thread on XML Character Styles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489531/import-xml-character-styles-into-indesign which leads to http://www.indesignusergroup.com/chapters/brisbane/files/643/Brisbane_Handout.pdf